# Snowflake python-connector; Error 604 when issuing multiple requests

Tags: python, sql, azure-functions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have an Azure Function that sends queries to snowflake using the Python snowflake-connector. It opens a connection, creates a cursor, sends the query and does not check to ensure the query was successful using _no_results=True. When I run it it works fine. However when I use it to run multiple queries at once, some queries are randomly failing with status code 604: Query Execution was canceled. Is there some sort of concurrent limit that I'm hitting? I cannot find any information in the documentation. The queries being sent are very simple (truncate table x) and are not timing out.

My code is attached below.

```
import logging
import json
import time
import gc
from flatten_json import flatten
import os
import snowflake.connector
import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    # Deserialize request body
    req_body = req.get_json()
    logging.info('Deserialized input successfully. Request body: '  +  json.dumps(req_body))

    #Create result JSON to be returned to caller
    result = {
        "TaskName":req_body['TaskName'],
        "Status":"Complete",
        "TaskKey": req_body['TaskKey'],
        "Query_ID":"",
        "Session_ID":""
        }

    #Create the Snowflake parameters for connection
    USER = <sfusername>
    PASSWD = <sfpw>
    ACCOUNT = <sfAcc>
    WAREHOUSE = <sfwh>
    DATABASE = <sfdb>

    logging.info('Connection string created')

    copy_sql_statement = create_sql_statement(req_body)
    logging.info('Insert SQL Statement: ' + copy_sql_statement)

    logging.info('Attempting to Connect to Snowflake...')    
    try:
        # Try to connect to Snowflake
        connection = snowflake.connector.connect(user=USER, password=PASSWD, account=ACCOUNT, warehouse=WAREHOUSE, database=DATABASE)
        logging.info('Connection Successful')
    except Exception as e:
        raise e

    logging.info('Try block for query_snowflake started.')
    try:
        # Call function to execute copy into
        output_list = query_snowflake(req_body, connection, copy_sql_statement) #return queryid and sessionid from Snowflake
        queryid = output_list[0]
        sessionid = output_list[1]
        result['Query_ID']= queryid
        result['Session_ID']= sessionid
        logging.info('Query sent to Snowflake Successfully.')
        return func.HttpResponse(json.dumps(result), status_code = 200)
    except Exception as e:
        result['Status'] = 'Failed'
        result['Error_Message'] = str(e)
        logging.info('Copy Into function failed.  Error: ' + str(e))
        return func.HttpResponse(json.dumps(result),
            status_code=400)

def create_sql_statement(req_body):
    # Replace TaskKey and CDCMin
    copy_sql_statement = req_body['InsertSQL'].replace('@TaskKey', req_body['TaskKey']).replace('@CDCMinDate', req_body['CDCMinDate']).replace('@CDCMaxDate', req_body['CDCMaxDate'])
    return copy_sql_statement

def query_snowflake(req_body, connection, copy_sql_statement):
    try:
        # Execute copy into statement
        cur = connection.cursor()   
        sessionid = cur.execute("select current_session()").fetchone()
        cur.execute(copy_sql_statement, _no_results=True)
        #connection.execute('COMMIT;')
        return [cur.sfqid, sessionid[0]] #return queryid and sessionid as list for result body
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
    #finally:
        # Close and dispose connection
        cur.close()
        connection.close()
```

NEW CODE:

```
import logging
import json
import time
import gc
from flatten_json import flatten
import os
import snowflake.connector
import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    # Deserialize request body
    req_body = req.get_json()
    logging.info('Deserialized input successfully. Request body: '  +  json.dumps(req_body))

    #Create result JSON to be returned to caller
    result = {
        "TaskName":req_body['TaskName'],
        "Status":"Complete",
        "TaskKey": req_body['TaskKey'],
        "Query_ID":"",
        "Session_ID":"",
        "Error_Message":""
        }

    #Create the Snowflake parameters for connection
    USER = <sfusername>
    PASSWD = <sfpw>
    ACCOUNT = <sfAcc>
    WAREHOUSE = <sfwh>
    DATABASE = <sfdb>

    logging.info('Connection string created')

    copy_sql_statement = create_sql_statement(req_body)
    logging.info('SQL Statement: ' + copy_sql_statement)

    logging.info('Attempting to Connect to Snowflake...')    
    try:
        # Try to connect to Snowflake
        connection = snowflake.connector.connect(user=USER, password=PASSWD, account=ACCOUNT, warehouse=WAREHOUSE, database=DATABASE)
        logging.info('Connection Successful')
    except Exception as e:
        raise e

    logging.info('Try block for send query started.')
    try:
        # Call function to execute copy into
        logging.info('Sending Query to Snowflake...')
        output_list = query_snowflake(req_body, connection, copy_sql_statement) #return queryid and sessionid from Snowflake
        queryid = output_list[0]
        sessionid = output_list[1]
        result['Query_ID']= queryid
        result['Session_ID']= sessionid

        logging.info('Ensuring Query was Sent...')
        status_stmt = create_status_statement(queryid, sessionid)
        for x in range(1,14): #it will try for 3.5min in case query is pending

            time.sleep(5)
            returnValues = get_query_status(status_stmt, connection) 

            # check result, if error code 604 we know the query canceled.
            if returnValues[1] == '604':
                result['Status'] = 'Failed'
                result['Error_Message'] = 'SQL Execution Canceled'
                return func.HttpResponse(json.dumps(result), status_code = 400)

            # if its anything but pending, we know the query was sent to snowflake
            # 2nd Function worries about the result
            elif returnValues[0] != 'PENDING':
                result['Status'] = returnValues[0]
                logging.info('Query sent to Snowflake Successfully.')
                return func.HttpResponse(json.dumps(result), status_code = 200)

            else:
                logging.info('Loop ' + str(x) + ' completed, trying again...')
                time.sleep(10)

        #if it exits for loop, mark success, let 2nd function surface any failures.
        result['Status'] = 'Success'
        return func.HttpResponse(json.dumps(result), status_code = 200)

    except Exception as e:
        result['Status'] = 'Failed'
        result['Error_Message'] = str(e)
        logging.info('Copy Into function failed.  Error: ' + str(e))
        return func.HttpResponse(json.dumps(result),
            status_code=400)

def create_sql_statement(req_body):
    # Replace TaskKey and CDCMin
    copy_sql_statement = req_body['InsertSQL'].replace('@TaskKey', req_body['TaskKey']).replace('@CDCMinDate', req_body['CDCMinDate']).replace('@CDCMaxDate', req_body['CDCMaxDate'])
    return copy_sql_statement

def query_snowflake(req_body, connection, copy_sql_statement):
    try:
        # Execute copy into statement
        cur = connection.cursor()   
        sessionid = cur.execute("select current_session()").fetchone()
        cur.execute(copy_sql_statement, _no_results=True)
        # return queryid and sessionid as list for result body
        return [cur.sfqid, sessionid[0]]
    except Exception as e:
        raise e

def create_status_statement(queryid, sessionid):

    sql_statement = "SELECT execution_status, error_code, query_id \
            FROM TABLE(INFORMATION_SCHEMA.QUERY_HISTORY_BY_SESSION(SESSION_ID => " + sessionid + ")) \
            WHERE QUERY_ID = '" + queryid + "'"
    return sql_statement

def get_query_status(etl_sql_statement, conn):

    QueryStatus = ''
    ErrorCode = ''
    QueryID = ''
   
    try:
        #Execute sql statement. 
        cur = conn.cursor()
        Result = cur.execute(etl_sql_statement)
        row = Result.fetchone()

        if row is None:
            ErrorCode = 'PENDING'
        else:
            QueryStatus = str(row[0])
            ErrorCode = str(row[1])
            QueryID = str(row[2])

    except Exception as e:
        logging.info('Failed to get query status. Error: ' + str(e))
        raise e

    finally:
        #Close and dispose cursor
        cur.close()

    return (QueryStatus, ErrorCode, QueryID)
```

Comment: Are the queries getting to Snowflake?  If so, what is the error that is shown from within Snowflake query history?

Comment: @MikeWalton They do get to snowflake. I am looking them up using INFORMATION_SCHEMA.QUERY_HISTORY_BY_SESSION and the error is Error code 604: SQL execution canceled

Comment: @MikeWalton Using the query history tab, I see they failed, due to the same error.

Comment: I'd have to test some stuff out, but it appears that you are closing your connection inside the query_snowflake function.  If you do that there, then it would kill the query that is being executed on Snowflake before it finishes executing.  So, in essence your code is cancelling the execution of the code.

Comment: @MikeWalton I've been doing a lot of testing and found that you are right, closing the connection is cancelling the query. I added additional logic so that my function will check the query_history to ensure the query has STATUS = "RUNNING" before closing the connection. However I'm finding that queries with status "RUNNING" are still being cancelled after the function closes. It looks like this is related to concurrency, the more queries running at once, the more likely it will be cancelled. Do you have any solutions to ensure a query will not be cancelled without waiting for completion?

Comment: What happens if you don't close the connection?

Comment: @MikeWalton I actually am no longer closing the connection or cursor, when it sees STATUS = "RUNNING" in the query history it exits the function with HTTP status = SUCCESS. I then have another function which checks the status and this second function is seeing the query is cancelled (when i check it I see the same thing). So it seems like the connection is closed when the function ends, and the connection closing is cancelling my query if there are multiple concurrent queries running at once. I've updated my original post with the new code directly below the old code.